# Using JQuery nextUntil to removeClass from all divs except the last in multiple sets

Tags: jquery

I have a collection of `div`s that is created dynamically.  These `div`s have one of two classes `.a` or `.b` which define how they are colored. There are certain rules that these `div`s follow:

- if there are two or more of the same div in a row, only the last div of that group should be colored
- `.a` is colored red
- `.b` is colored blue

I am currently trying to use selectors as follows

```js
//trying to color all final as
$('.a').nextUntil('.b').addBack().removeClass('colored');
$('.a').nextUntil('.b').addBack().last().addClass('colored');

//trying to color all final bs using not
$('.b').nextUntil(':not(.b)').addBack().removeClass('colored');
$('.b').nextUntil(':not(.b)').addBack().last().addClass('colored');
```

```css
.a{
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.b{
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.a.colored{
  background-color:red;
}
.b.colored{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a">a1</div>
<div class="a">a2</div>
<div class="a">a3</div>
<div class="b">b1</div>
<div class="b">b2</div>
<div class="b">b3</div>
<div class="a">a4</div>
<div class="a">a5</div>
<div class="b">b4</div>
<div class="a">a6</div>
<div class="b">b5</div>
```

I was expecting this to color `a3`, `a5`, and `a6` red, and to color `b3`, `b4`, and `b5` blue.  However, it seems to only affect the very last div of each class (`a6` and `b5`).

Is it possible to use `nextUntil()` to color the last div of each sequential set of the same class?  If not, what can I use to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
$('.a').each(function(){
    var $sibling = $(this).next();

  if($sibling.hasClass('b') || $(this).is(':last-child')){
    $(this).addClass('colored');
  }

});

$('.b').each(function(){
    var $sibling = $(this).next();

  if($sibling.hasClass('a') || $(this).is(':last-child')){
    $(this).addClass('colored');
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/webyhyxb/

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```
$('.b').prev('.a').addClass('colored').end().last().addClass('colored')

$('.a').prev('.b').addClass('colored').end().last().addClass('colored');
```

Below  the working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ztqspovn/

Comment: What a beautiful and simple answer!  I only chose the other because it came first and, due to my circumstances, that's the one that I had to end up using.

Answer (score 1):

```
this is for dynamic solution . we can write N number of classes for this
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ztqspovn/4/